# Stored procedure dynamic query with if

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in which I have to compare the values using `=`, `<`, `>` as a parameter and compare it with the another parameter value rating which has the value 1,2,3,4,5 but not have any idea how to do that please help.

Here is my stored procedure what I have tried so far, and I have three tables `user`, `RatingReview` and `accounttype` :

```
Create Procedure searchsp_LenderSearch
    @pAccountTypeId int =null,
    @pFirstName varchar(25)=null,
    @pLastName varchar(35)=null,
    @pZip varchar(10)=null,
    @pOperator varchar(2)=null,
    @pRating varchar(2)=null
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
Declare @SQLQuery AS NVarchar(4000)
    SET @SQLQuery=
  'select 
   at.AccountName,
   U.UserId,
   U.FirstName,
   U.LastName,
   U.NMLS,
   U.[Address],
   U.PrimaryEmailId As Office,
   U.AdditionalEmail As Personal,
   U.DirectPhone As Work,
   U.Mobile,
   R.RatingStar

    from [User] U
    left outer join  RatingReview R   on R.UserId =U.UserId
    left outer join AccountType at on at.AccountTypeId = U.AccountTypeId
  where U.Deleted =0
  AND at.AccountTypeId = '+CAST(@pAccountTypeId as Varchar(10))+'
  AND U.FirstName = ''' + @pFirstName + '''
  AND U.LastName = ''' + @pLastName + '''
  AND U.Zip = ''' + @pZip + '''
  AND R.RatingStar = ''' + @pRating  + ''''


 IF(@pAccountTypeId  !=null OR @pAccountTypeId  != '')

    BEGIN
        SET @SQLQuery=@SQLQuery+' AND at.AccountTypeId='+CONVERT(VARCHAR, @pAccountTypeId )
    END

   IF(@pFirstName !=null OR @pFirstName != '')
    BEGIN
        SET @SQLQuery=@SQLQuery+' AND U.FirstName Like ''%' + @pFirstName + '%'''
    END

    IF(@pLastName !=null OR @pLastName != '')
    BEGIN
        SET @SQLQuery=@SQLQuery+' AND U.LastName Like ''%' + @pLastName + '%'''
    END

    IF(@pZip !=null OR @pZip != '')
    BEGIN
        SET @SQLQuery=@SQLQuery+' AND U.Zip Like ''%' + @pZip + '%'''
    END

    IF(@pRating !=null OR @pRating != '')
    BEGIN
        SET @SQLQuery=@SQLQuery+' AND R.RatingStar Like ''%' + @pRating + '%'''
    END

   IF(@pOperator = '=')
    BEGIN
    SET @SQLQuery += ' AND R.RatingStar = ' + CAST(@pRating AS NVARCHAR(5)) + ''
    END

    IF(@pOperator = '>')
        BEGIN
        SET @SQLQuery += ' AND R.RatingStar > ' + CAST(@pRating AS NVARCHAR(5)) + ''
        END

    IF(@pOperator = '<')
        BEGIN
        SET @SQLQuery += ' AND R.RatingStar < ' + CAST(@pRating AS NVARCHAR(5)) + ''
        END
        SET @SQLQuery=@SQLQuery+
  'group by 
  at.AccountName,
  U.UserId,
   U.FirstName,
   U.LastName,
   U.NMLS,
   U.[Address],
   U.PrimaryEmailId,
   U.AdditionalEmail,
   U.DirectPhone,
   U.Mobile,
   R.RatingStar'

   EXEC (@SQLQuery) 
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the parameters you pass into the query to concatenate them in the `@sqlstring` variable. Try this query:

```
Create PROCEDURE searchsp_LenderSearch
    @pAccountType int,
    @pFirstName varchar(25),
    @pLastName varchar(35),
    @pZip varchar(10),
    @pOperator varchar(2),
    @pRating int 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @SQLQuery AS NVarchar(4000)
    SET @SQLQuery = '
SELECT 
    at.AccountTypeId,
    U.UserId,
    U.FirstName,
    U.LastName,
    R.RatingStar AS Rating,
    U.NMLS,
    U.[Address],
    U.PrimaryEmailId As Office,
    U.AdditionalEmail As Personal,
    U.DirectPhone As Work,
    U.Mobile
FROM [User] U
LEFT OUTER JOIN RatingReview R ON R.UserId = U.UserId
LEFT OUTER JOIN AccountType at ON at.AccountTypeId = U.AccountTypeId
WHERE U.Deleted = 0
  AND at.AccountTypeId = 1
  AND U.FirstName = ''' + @pFirstName + '''
  AND U.LastName = ''' + @pLastName + '''
  AND U.Zip = ''' + @pZip + ''''

IF(@pOperator = '=')
    BEGIN
    SET @SQLQuery += ' AND r.ratingstar = ' + CAST(@pRating AS NVARCHAR(5)) + ''
    END
IF(@pOperator = '<')
    BEGIN
    SET @SQLQuery += ' AND r.ratingstar < ' + CAST(@pRating AS NVARCHAR(5)) + ''
    END
IF(@pOperator = '>')
    BEGIN
    SET @SQLQuery += ' AND r.ratingstar > ' + CAST(@pRating AS NVARCHAR(5)) + ''
    END

SET @SQLQuery += '
GROUP BY 
    at.AccountTypeId,
    U.UserId,
    U.FirstName,
    U.LastName,
    U.NMLS,
    U.[Address],
    U.PrimaryEmailId,
    U.AdditionalEmail,
    U.DirectPhone,
    U.Mobile,
    R.RatingStar'
EXEC (@SQLQuery) 
END
```

The code above will generate a query like:

```
SELECT 
    at.AccountTypeId,
    U.UserId,
    U.FirstName,
    U.LastName,
    R.RatingStar AS Rating,
    U.NMLS,
    U.[Address],
    U.PrimaryEmailId As Office,
    U.AdditionalEmail As Personal,
    U.DirectPhone As Work,
    U.Mobile
FROM [User] U
LEFT OUTER JOIN RatingReview R ON R.UserId = U.UserId
LEFT OUTER JOIN AccountType at ON at.AccountTypeId = U.AccountTypeId
WHERE U.Deleted = 0
  AND at.AccountTypeId = 1
  AND U.FirstName = 'John'
  AND U.LastName = 'Adams'
  AND U.Zip = '100AA' AND r.ratingstar > 1
GROUP BY 
    at.AccountTypeId,
    U.UserId,
    U.FirstName,
    U.LastName,
    U.NMLS,
    U.[Address],
    U.PrimaryEmailId,
    U.AdditionalEmail,
    U.DirectPhone,
    U.Mobile,
    R.RatingStar
```

if executed like `exec searchsp_LenderSearch 1, 'John', 'Adams', '100AA', '>',1`

I think this is what you want. Obviously you might want to add some error checking and validation of parameters etc.

As requested here is an updated version of the query changed to match the updated question:

```
Create Procedure searchsp_LenderSearch
    @pAccountTypeId int       = null,
    @pFirstName varchar(25) = null,
    @pLastName      varchar(35) = null,
    @pZip           varchar(10) = null,
    @pOperator      varchar(2)  = null,
    @pRating        varchar(2)  = null
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @SQLQuery AS NVarchar(4000)
    SET @SQLQuery ='
SELECT 
    at.AccountName,
    U.UserId,
    U.FirstName,
    U.LastName,
    U.NMLS,
    U.[Address],
    U.PrimaryEmailId As Office,
    U.AdditionalEmail As Personal,
    U.DirectPhone As Work,
    U.Mobile,
    R.RatingStar
FROM [User] U
LEFT OUTER JOIN RatingReview R ON R.UserId = U.UserId
LEFT OUTER JOIN AccountType at ON at.AccountTypeId = U.AccountTypeId
WHERE U.Deleted = 0
 '
IF(@pAccountTypeId  !=null OR @pAccountTypeId  != '')
    BEGIN
        SET @SQLQuery += ' AND at.AccountTypeId = '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @pAccountTypeId ) + '' 
    END

IF(@pFirstName !=null OR @pFirstName != '')
    BEGIN
        SET @SQLQuery += ' AND U.FirstName Like ''%' + @pFirstName + '%'''
    END

IF(@pLastName !=null OR @pLastName != '')
    BEGIN
        SET @SQLQuery += ' AND U.LastName Like ''%' + @pLastName + '%'''
    END

IF(@pZip !=null OR @pZip != '')
    BEGIN
        SET @SQLQuery += ' AND U.Zip Like ''%' + @pZip + '%'''
    END

IF(@pOperator = '=')
    BEGIN
        SET @SQLQuery += ' AND R.RatingStar = ' + CAST(@pRating AS NVARCHAR(5)) + ''
    END

IF(@pOperator = '>')
    BEGIN
        SET @SQLQuery += ' AND R.RatingStar > ' + CAST(@pRating AS NVARCHAR(5)) + ''
    END

IF(@pOperator = '<')
    BEGIN
        SET @SQLQuery += ' AND R.RatingStar < ' + CAST(@pRating AS NVARCHAR(5)) + ''
    END

SET @SQLQuery += '
GROUP BY 
    at.AccountName,
    U.UserId,
    U.FirstName,
    U.LastName,
    U.NMLS,
    U.[Address],
    U.PrimaryEmailId,
    U.AdditionalEmail,
    U.DirectPhone,
    U.Mobile,
    R.RatingStar'

    EXEC (@SQLQuery) 
   --PRINT (@SQLQuery) 
END
```

Comment: Thank you So much Sir @ jpw . it helps a lot

Comment: sir while implementing the above condition exec searchsp_LenderSearch 1, 'John', 'Adams', '100AA', '=',5 is working but the condition exec searchsp_LenderSearch 1, 'John', 'Adams', '100AA', '>',1 is not working . can you please help me on this

Comment: sir i have updated my question Please have a look in which exec searchsp_LenderSearch 1, 'John', 'Adams', '100AA', '=',5  this condition is working fine but when i do the same like exec searchsp_LenderSearch 1, 'John', 'Adams', '100AA', '>',1 its not showing me that record . can you please help me.

Comment: @ReshavChandanSingh I think the problem is that you have two mutually exclusive conditions since you both have `AND R.RatingStar = ''' + @pRating  + ''''` and then the dynamic chosen condition for the operator, for example `SET @SQLQuery += ' AND R.RatingStar > ' + CAST(@pRating AS NVARCHAR(5)) + ''` The conditions can't be true at the same time so I think you need to remove the first.

Comment: sir can you please please update you answer according to my updated answer, I'll be very grateful .

Comment: @ReshavChandanSingh Sure I can give it a try.

Comment: @ReshavChandanSingh I've added an updated query at the end of the answer; I removed the mutually exclusive conditions and I think it should work.

Comment: sir there is one problem i am facing that i have zip in the form of comma seprated string where i am checking the condition like 
And U.Zip in ('+@pZipList+') its giving me an error when the value is null how can i avoid this please help.